# Instagram Graph API Webhooks on behalf of another user

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Instagram Graph API Webhooks on behalf of another user. The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/webhooks/) is very vague about this, and it seems to me that all I can do is get data from my account account. Is that correct?

We have a reviewed app (the new Instagram Graph API) so users can authenticate them selves in our app, which allows us to get insights data from their Instagram Business Accounts on their behalf.

According to the documentation it seems that each user that wants insights for when their stories expire for example, need to set up an app and configure the webhooks themselves. Shouldn't it be enough that we do this and then setup subscriptions based on the users that have allowed us to pull their data from their accounts?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, did you managed to find a solution ?